# Flink java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.libs.json.Reads

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

i´m writing a code that reads from a text file and parse every line as a Json, but the job in Flink (1.0.3 - Cluster with 2 Taskmanagers) fails with the th excetion: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.libs.json.Reads`

My code:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}

object rabbitjob {

case class MyJson(pr: Long,
                dv: Long,
                ty: Int,
                cr: String,
                rc: String,
                vl: Boolean,
                ss: String,
                id: Long
               )

def main (args:Array[String]){
  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  val stream = env.readTextFile("hdfs:///test/ignicion.io")

  implicit val myJsonReads = Json.reads[MyJson]

  def jsontr(cuerpo: String): Unit ={

     val inputJson = Json.parse(cuerpo)
     val myJsonInstance: MyJson = inputJson.as[MyJson]

     println(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis() + " " +  myJsonInstance.cr + " " + matchtype(myJsonInstance.ty) + " " + " " + matchvalue(myJsonInstance.vl))

  def matchtype (x: Int): String = x match{
      case 1 => "Door"
      case 2 => "Window"
      case _ => "otros"
    }

  def matchvalue (x: Boolean): String = x match{
      case true => "ON"
      case false => "OFF"
    }
  }

  println(stream)
  stream.map(jsontr(_))

 env.execute("Test Rabbit")
 }
}
```

Any idea about it?? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to package all external dependencies together with your Flink program  into a "fat" JAR file that you submit to the cluster.

The Flink documentation shows how to do that with [Maven](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/cluster_execution.html#packaging-dependencies-with-your-usercode-with-maven).

Comment: Thank you Fabian. Done, including joda-time and com.typesafe.play. A new error: `Task not serializable`

Comment: Flink serializes and ships user function object using Java serialization. Hence they must be serializable.

Comment: i think so, perhaps something in my code is not the correct way to do it.